# Azure release pipeline for Spring Boot app says it has no artifact to publish

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to deploy my Spring Boot (Java) app on Azure using Azure DevOps. However, I cant seem to get the release pipeline working.

I already created an Azure build pipeline with the following azure-pipelines.yml:

```html
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'package'
    options: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true'
    mavenOptions: '-Dmaven.test.skip=true'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
```

The build is successful, so the next step is to create a Release pipeline. I selected the option 'Deploy a Java app to Azure App Service'. When I try to add the artifact, then I see the following:
[image: Screenshot of Azure release pipeline]

As you can see, I get the message **'No version is available for  or the latest version has no artifacts to publish. Please check the source pipeline.'**. This tells me that the build pipeline did not create the artifact or that some other setting is configure incorrectly. My initial thought is that I need to add a step to azure-pipelines.yml that actually puts the artifact somewhere.

Does anyone know what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This tells me that the build pipeline did not create the artifact or that some other setting is configure incorrectly. My initial thought is that I need to add a step to azure-pipelines.yml that actually puts the artifact somewhere.

Yes, your initial thought is completely correct.

When you use the release pipeline to deploy the app/file, which will get the source from the artifact. So, we need to publish the app/file to the artifact in our build pipeline. The build output is in the working directory not published to the artifact, that is the reason why you get the error, *No version is available for or the latest version has no artifacts to publish*.

**To resolve this issue**, you just need to add [copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Publish build artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) after Maven task to copy the .jar file and publish it to the artifacts:

```
steps:
- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'package'
    ...

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*.jar'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Then, we could use the release pipeline to deploy the build artifact:

[image]

Comment: This resolved my issue. Indeed we should add tasks that copy the files and publish the artifacts. Thank you!